# Understanding gruntjs registerTask colon

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm currently trying to learn gruntjs for dev and production build.

I want to assign a global config variable to determine stuff.
I have a simple `initConfig` :

```
grunt.initConfig({
  foo: {
    bar: {GLOBAL: true},
    baz: {GLOBAL: false}
  }
});

grunt.registerTask('one', ['foo:bar']);
grunt.registerTask('two', ['foo:baz']);
```

My question is:

> What exactly is the colon in my tasks doing? (`foo:bar` or `foo:baz`)
>
> And what is the difference between a colon and a simple dot?

My Goal is to have a global variable set either to `true` or `false` for further processing:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  foo: {
    bar: {GLOBAL: true},
    baz: {GLOBAL: false}
  },
  
  awesomestuff: {
    smth: GLOBAL ? 'yes' : 'no',
    another: !Global ? 'DoDebug' : 'MakeRelease'
  }
});

grunt.registerTask('one', ['foo:bar', 'awesomestuff']);
grunt.registerTask('two', ['foo:baz', 'awesomestuff']);
```

> How would I achieve this?

---

## Update

I got the global variable working somehow. By registering a new new task called `init` with an argument I can call it in an other task.

```
grunt.registerTask('init', 'Init', function(param) {
   grunt.config('GLOBAL', param)
 });


grunt.registerTask('one', ['init:true', 'foo:bar', 'awesomestuff']);
```

In this case the `init` task will be called with the vairable `param` set to `true`.
But the question is still:

> Why would I use a colon insted of a dot to reference an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why would I use a colon instead of a dot to reference an object?

To understand why, you firstly need to understand *grunt* [task configurations and targets](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets).

**Single Target**

To help you further understand this concept and terminology, take a look at this [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-copy#usage-examples) configuration for a *grunt* plugin called `grunt-contrib-copy`. It's a plugin that copies files. Below is a snippet of that code:

```js
grunt.initConfig({

    copy: { // <-- Task
        main: { // <-- Target
            // ... <-- other configurations go here.
        }
    }

});
```

In this example above the *Task* is named `copy` and it includes a single *Target* named `main`.

To register this *Task* you would do so as follows:

```js
grunt.registerTask('copyFiles', ['copy:main']);
```

and you would enter the following via your command line to run it:

`$ grunt copyFiles`

**Multiple Targets**

Grunt *Tasks* can also include more than one *Target*. Consider this example code below:

```js
grunt.initConfig({
    copy: {
        js: {
            // ... <-- Additional configurations for this Target go here.
        },
        css: {
            // ... <-- Additional configurations for this Target go here.
        }
    }
});
```

You could register the example above as follows:

```js
grunt.registerTask('copyJavaScriptFiles', ['copy:js']);
grunt.registerTask('copyCssFiles', ['copy:css']);
```

So, via the command line:

1. Running `$ grunt copyJavaScriptFiles` will copy all the JS files according to the configurations specified.
2. Running `$ grunt copyCssFiles` will copy all the CSS files according to the configurations specified.

If you wanted to copy both the JS and CSS files you could register a task as follows:

```js
grunt.registerTask('copyAll', ['copy']);
```

And you would run it by entering `$ grunt copyAll` in your command line.

Notice in the last example it does not include any colon `:`. Grunt this time will run all the `Targets` in the `copy` *Task*, namely the `js` one and the `css` one.

---

> And what is the difference between a colon and a simple dot?

**Colon**

Hopefully by now you can see what the colon `:` does. It is used to reference a particular [Target](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) within a Task and is typically only used when a *Task* has multiple *Targets* and you want to specifically reference one of them.

**Simple dot**

The simple dot is JavaScript's standard notation to access properties of an object. Google *"JavaScript notation"* to find out more about *Dot Notation* and *Square Bracket Notation*.

Within the context of your *Gruntfile.js* the dot notation is typically used to call the functions/methods/properties of the `grunt` object. For example:

```js
grunt.initConfig({...});

grunt.loadNpmTasks(...);

grunt.registerTask(...);
```

---

**EDIT 1** Updated the answer after the original post/question was updated.

Comment: I misunderstood some features of grunt. As I understand the colons are used to pass arguments to tasks. I was not aware that when I'm using an NpmTask such as `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');` and my custom task e.g.: `grunt.registerTask('foo', ['browserify:dev']);` would actually execute a task with given parameter and not assign a variable.

Thanks!