# Grunt how to run task with different arguments

Tags: gruntjs, frontend

The source config example below processes files from `src` dir. There is `src2` dir which also should be processed with the same tasks and putted to `build2`. What changes required in config.

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  var saveLicense = require('uglify-save-license');

  grunt.initConfig({
    clean : {
      build : {
        src : ['build']
      },
    },
    copy : {
      files : {
        cwd : 'src',
        src : '**/*',
        dest : 'build',
        expand : true
      }
    },
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Both [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) and [grunt-contrib-clean](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean), like many other grunt plugins, allow multiple [Targets](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) to be specified in each [Task](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets).

For your scenario you can simply configure two Targets in the `copy` task *(one Target to copy the `src` folder and another Target to copy the `src2` folder)*.

You can also configure two Targets in the `clean` task *(one Target to clean the `build` folder and another Target to clean the `build2` folder)*.

**Gruntfile.js**

Your `Gruntfile.js` can be configured as ass follows:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    var saveLicense = require('uglify-save-license');

    grunt.initConfig({

        // The 'clean' task now includes two targets.
        // named 'build1' and 'build2'
        clean: {
            build1: {
                src: ['build']
            },
            build2: {
                src: ['build2']
            }
        },

        // The 'copy' task now includes two targets.
        // named 'src1' and 'src2'
        copy: {
            src1: {
                cwd: 'src',
                src: '**/*',
                dest: 'build',
                expand: true
            },
            src2: {
                cwd: 'src2',
                src: '**/*',
                dest: 'build2',
                expand: true
            }
        }

        // ...

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');

    // Registering the Targets in the Tasks....

    grunt.registerTask('copySrc1', ['copy:src1']);
    grunt.registerTask('cleanBuild1', ['clean:build1']);

    grunt.registerTask('copySrc2', ['copy:src2']);
    grunt.registerTask('cleanBuild2', ['clean:build2']);

    grunt.registerTask('copyBoth', ['copy']);
    grunt.registerTask('cleanBoth', ['clean']);

};
```

**Running the Grunt Tasks**

You'll notice that there are six calls to the `.registerTask(...)` function at the end of the snippet. Namely; `copySrc1`, `cleanBuild1`, `copySrc2`, `cleanBuild2`, `copyBoth`, and `cleanBoth`.

They allow you to run the following commands via your command line:

`$ grunt copySrc1`

*(This will copy the `src` folder to the `build` folder)*

---

`$ grunt cleanBuild1`

*(This will clean the `build` folder)*

---

`$ grunt copySrc1`

*(This will copy the `src2` folder to the `build2` folder)*

---

`$ grunt cleanBuild2`

*(This will clean the `build2` folder)*

---

`$ grunt copyBoth`

*(This will copy the `src` folder to the `build` folder and copy the `src2` folder to the `build2` folder)*

---

`$ grunt cleanBoth`

*(This will clean both the `build` and `build2` folders)*

---

**Notes**

You probably only need to keep the two `.registerTask(...)` functions as follows:

```js
grunt.registerTask('copyBoth', ['copy']);
grunt.registerTask('cleanBoth', ['clean']);
```

However, I included the other four `.registerTask(...)` functions as they demonstrate how you can call a single Target inside a Task using the semicolon notation (`:`). For example:

```js
grunt.registerTask('copySrc1', ['copy:src1']);
```

In the above snippet the `['copy:src1']` part simply runs only the Target named `src1` inside the `copy` Task.

Whereas:

```js
grunt.registerTask('copyBoth', ['copy']);
```

... does not reference any Targets in the `copy` task, (i.e. no semicolon notation is used), therefore all Targets will be run.

To further understand Tasks, Targets, you can read my answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42578146/understanding-gruntjs-registertask-colon/42582084#42582084).

Hope that helps!